# Ignore small words, in word count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this word count script:

http://jsfiddle.net/ChrT8/1/

```
counter = function() {
    var value = $('#text').val();

    if (value.length == 0) {
        $('#wordCount').html(0);

        return;
    }

    var regex = /\s+/gi;
    var wordCount = value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length; 


    $('#wordCount').html(wordCount);

};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#count').click(counter);
    $('#text').change(counter);
    $('#text').keydown(counter);
    $('#text').keypress(counter);
    $('#text').keyup(counter);
    $('#text').blur(counter);
    $('#text').focus(counter);
});
```

How can I make it ignore words that are under 3 characters? Like I want it to ignore things like: "Yes,no,at,b,.,;,2" etc

Other code improvements greatly appreciated, im not a programmer, and I cant  figure it out

I've tried adding

```
 (if this.value > 2) {  value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length; }
```

Sadly it did not work

Comment: you can add `.filter(function(v){ return v.length>2 })` just before the `.length`.

Comment: It would probably be better to use a list of unwanted words and remove those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace

```
var regex = /\s+/gi;
var wordCount = value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length;
```

with

```
var wordCount = value.split(/\s+/)
                     .filter(function(v){ return v.length>2 })
                     .length;
```

or

```
var wordCount = value.match(/\b\w{3,}\b/g).length;
```

Comment: Regarding my last regex, it depends on what you see as a word. If you want to accept anything that isn't a space, use `value.match(/\b\S{3,}\b/g).length;`

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is incorrect. Try:

```
var regex = /\s+/gi;
var words = value.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ');
var wordCount
for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    if(words[i].length > 2) wordCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `input` event instead of what you're doing with all those other event listeners and also use `filter` to filter out the short words.

```
var $textarea = $('textarea'), $counter = $('.counter');

$textarea.on('input', function () {

  var wordCount = $textarea.val().split(' ').filter(function(word){
    return word.length > 2;
  }).length;

  $counter.html('There is ' + wordCount + ' words in here!');

}).trigger('input');
```

Here is a small demo: http://jsbin.com/dajapono/2/edit?js,output